# Why am I receiving an error at my "for" loop saying 'break' statement not in loop or switch?

Tags: c

incredibly new to programming I am receiving an error on line 12 stating that my break statement is not in the loop or switch. Can anyone explain where my error is and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n1, n2, i, gcd, lcm;

    printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);

    for(i=1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; ++i) {
        printf("Enter two positive integers: ");
        scanf("%d %d",&n1,&n2);
        if(n1==-1,n2==-1) break;
        // Checks if i is factor of both integers
        if(n1%i==0 && n2%i==0)
           gcd = i;
    }

    lcm = (n1*n2)/gcd;
    printf("The LCM of two numbers %d and %d is %d.", n1, n2, lcm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(n1==-1,n2==-1)` Can you explain this?

Comment: If you're incredibly new, Stack Overflow probably isn't the right place for you. There are many freely available tutorial resources that you should spend some time with. Once you have a grasp of the basics, you may find this website useful for specific, well-researched questions.

Comment: The break statement is on line 15 (not 12) - Are you sure we are looking at the same code as you?

Comment: Line 15 change it to  -  if(n1==-1 && n2==-1) break;

Comment: This code compiles without a error.

Comment: `gcd` is uninitialised in some control paths. Used as divisor ... bad juju.

Comment: This is not the code that is causing your error, this code compiles cleanly. Voting to close as incorrect information given.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "receiving an error on line 12 stating that my break statement is not in the loop or switch" then either you have a very deficient compiler or you've posted the wrong code. That code has a *few* problems but a `break` in the wrong place is not one of them.

That particular error message often occurs when you've mislaid some braces, along the lines of:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if (someCondition)
        break;
```

That's because, despite the fact it *looks* like you're breaking out of a loop, the actual `break` statement is not *within* the loop. Only the `printf` is.

In terms of the code you *have* provided, there are numerous ways to clean it up:

- Remove unneeded includes.
- Refactor out the number input to a common function.
- Allow a single non-positive number to terminate the program.
- Use `DRY` principle for input, there's really any need to duplicate code segments if you structure it corretly.
- Make input more robust, allowing for invalid numbers.
- Add more comments, these will greatly assist you (or others who have to maintain your code) in the future.
- Use better variable names. Other than `i` for small localised loops, I almost *never* use single-character variable names.
- Fix the `if(n1==-1,n2==-1)` bit. That doesn't do what you appear to think it does. The comma operator will *evaluate* both expressions but the result of the full expression is the rightmost one. So it's effectively `if(n2==-1)`.

To that end, the following is how *I* would write the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ERR_NON_POS -1
#define ERR_INVALID -2

// Gets a single number.
//  If non-positive or invalid, returns error (a negative value ERR_*).
//  Otherwise, returns the (positive) number.

int getNumber(void) {
    int number;
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1) return -2;
    if (number <= 0) return -1;
    return number;
}

int main(void) {
    // Infinite loop, we'll break from within as needed.

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter two positive integers (a negative number will stop): ");

        // Do it one at a time so a SINGLE negative number can stop.

        int number1 = getNumber();
        if (number1 == ERR_INVALID) {
            puts("** Non-integral value entered");
            break;
        }
        if (number1 == ERR_NON_POS) break;

        int number2 = getNumber();
        if (number2 == ERR_INVALID) {
            puts("** Non-integral value entered");
            break;
        }
        if (number2 == ERR_NON_POS) break;

        // Work out greatest common divisor (though there are better ways
        //  to do this than checking EVERY possibility).

        int gcd = 1;
        for (int i = 2; (i <= number1) && (i <= number2); ++i) {
            if (number1 % i == 0 && number2 % i == 0) {
                gcd = i;
            }
        }

        // Work out the lowest common multiple.

        int lcm = number1 * number2 / gcd;

        // Print them both and go get more.

        printf("For numbers %d and %d, GCD is %d and LCM is %d.\n", number1, number2, gcd, lcm);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

And, if you're wondering about the more efficient way of calculating GCD, you should look into Euclid's algorithm. This can be defined as (for non-negative `a` and `b`):

```
gcd(a,b) = a               if b is zero
           gcd(b, a mod b) if b is non-zero
```

That means you can have a recursive function:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Or an iterative one if you're vehemently opposed to recursion:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int t = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```